# EC2 Storm cluster Netty problems

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, netty, apache-storm

I have the following EC2 setup:

1) 3x m4.xlarge nodes for a 3-node ZooKeeper ensemble and a nimbus

2) 4x m4.xlarge nodes for my Supervisors.

All of the machines are running Ubuntu Linux v14, OpenJDK v1.7 and Apache Storm v0.9.4. The storm.yaml I am currently having in the nimbus node (only) has the following values:

```
storm.home: "/opt/apache-storm-0.9.4"
storm.local.dir: "/mnt/storm"
storm.zookeeper.servers:
     - "172.31.28.73"
     - "172.31.38.251"
     - "172.31.38.252"
storm.zookeeper.port: 2181
storm.zookeeper.root: "/storm"
storm.zookeeper.session.timeout: 20000
storm.zookeeper.connection.timeout: 15000
storm.zookeeper.retry.times: 5
storm.zookeeper.retry.interval: 1000
storm.zookeeper.retry.invervalceiling.millis: 30000
storm.cluster.mode: "distributed"
storm.local.mode.zmq: false
storm.thrift.transport: "backtype.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin"
storm.messaging.transport: "backtype.storm.messaging.netty.Context"

nimbus.host: "127.0.0.1"
nimbus.thrift.port: 6627
nimbus.thrift.max_buffer_size: 1048576
nimbus.thrift.threads: 256
nimbus.childopts: "-Xmx256m"
nimbus.task.timeout.secs: 30
nimbus.supervisor.timeout.secs: 60
nimbus.monitor.freq.secs: 10
nimbus.cleanup.inbox.freq.secs: 600
nimbus.inbox.jar.expiration.secs: 3600
nimbus.task.launch.secs: 120
nimbus.reassign: true
nimbus.file.copy.expiration.secs: 600
nimbus.topology.validator: "backtype.storm.nimbus.DefaultTopologyValidator"

ui.port: 8080
ui.childopts: "-Xmx768m"
logviewer.port: 8000
logviewer.childopts: "-Xmx256m"
logviewer.appender.name: "A1"

drpc.port: 3772
drpc.worker.threads: 64
drpc.queue.size: 128
drpc.invocations.port: 3773
drpc.request.timeout.secs: 600
drpc.childopts: "-Xmx768m"

transactional.zookeeper.root: "/transactional"
transactional.zookeeper.servers: null
transactional.zookeeper.port: null

supervisor.slots.ports:
     - 6700
     - 6701
     - 6702
     - 6703
supervisor.childopts: "-Xmx256m"
supervisor.worker.start.timeout.secs: 120
supervisor.worker.timeout.secs: 30
supervisor.monitor.frequency.secs: 3
supervisor.heartbeat.frequency.secs: 5
supervisor.enable: true

worker.childopts: "-Xmx4096m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:NewSize=128m -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX: -CMSConcurrentMTEnabled -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
worker.heartbeat.frequency.secs: 1

task.heartbeat.frequency.secs: 3
task.refresh.poll.secs: 10

zmq.threads: 1
zmq.linger.millis: 5000
zmq.hwm: 0

storm.messaging.netty.server_worker_threads: 4
storm.messaging.netty.client_worker_threads: 4
storm.messaging.netty.buffer_size: 10485760
storm.messaging.netty.max_retries: 100
storm.messaging.netty.max_wait_ms: 1000
storm.messaging.netty.min_wait_ms: 100
topology.enable.message.timeouts: true
topology.debug: false
topology.optimize: true
topology.workers: 1
topology.acker.executors: null
topology.tasks: null
topology.message.timeout.secs: 30
topology.skip.missing.kryo.registrations: false
topology.max.task.parallelism: null
topology.max.spout.pending: null
topology.state.synchronization.timeout.secs: 60
topology.stats.sample.rate: 0.05
topology.builtin.metrics.bucket.size.secs: 60
topology.fall.back.on.java.serialization: true
topology.worker.childopts: null
topology.executor.receive.buffer.size: 1024
topology.executor.send.buffer.size: 1024
topology.receiver.buffer.size: 8
topology.transfer.buffer.size: 1024
topology.tick.tuple.freq.secs: null
topology.worker.shared.thread.pool.size: 4
topology.disruptor.wait.strategy: "com.lmax.disruptor.BlockingWaitStrategy"
topology.spout.wait.strategy: "backtype.storm.spout.SleepSpoutWaitStrategy"
topology.sleep.spout.wait.strategy.time.ms: 1
topology.error.throttle.interval.secs: 10
topology.max.error.report.per.interval: 5
topology.kryo.factory: "backtype.storm.serialization.DefaultKryoFactory"
topology.tuple.serializer: "backtype.storm.serialization.types.ListDelegateSerializer"
topology.trident.batch.emit.interval.millis: 500

dev.zookeeper.path: "/tmp/dev-storm-zookeeper"
```

The problem is that every time I submit a topology, I got a lot of Netty messages in my worker logs (found in the supervisor machines) and 
many of them had similar to the following messages:

```
2015-06-25T19:42:32.534+0000 b.s.u.StormBoundedExponentialBackoffRetry [INFO] The baseSleepTimeMs [1000] the maxSleepTimeMs [30000] the maxRetries [5]
2015-06-25T19:42:32.625+0000 o.a.s.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl [INFO] Starting
2015-06-25T19:42:32.629+0000 o.a.s.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Initiating client connection, connectString=172.31.28.73:2181,172.31.38.251:2181,172.31.38.252:2181 sessionTimeout=20000 watcher=org.apache.storm.curator.ConnectionState@5172aa5a
2015-06-25T19:42:32.649+0000 o.a.s.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Opening socket connection to server 172.31.28.73/172.31.28.73:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-06-25T19:42:32.655+0000 o.a.s.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Socket connection established to 172.31.28.73/172.31.28.73:2181, initiating session
2015-06-25T19:42:32.670+0000 o.a.s.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Session establishment complete on server 172.31.28.73/172.31.28.73:2181, sessionid = 0x14e2b0caa01005f, negotiated timeout = 20000
2015-06-25T19:42:32.672+0000 o.a.s.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager [INFO] State change: CONNECTED
2015-06-25T19:42:32.674+0000 b.s.zookeeper [INFO] Zookeeper state update: :connected:none
2015-06-25T19:42:32.703+0000 o.a.s.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] EventThread shut down
2015-06-25T19:42:32.703+0000 o.a.s.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Session: 0x14e2b0caa01005f closed
2015-06-25T19:42:32.705+0000 b.s.u.StormBoundedExponentialBackoffRetry [INFO] The baseSleepTimeMs [1000] the maxSleepTimeMs [30000] the maxRetries [5]
2015-06-25T19:42:32.706+0000 o.a.s.c.f.i.CuratorFrameworkImpl [INFO] Starting
2015-06-25T19:42:32.716+0000 o.a.s.z.ZooKeeper [INFO] Initiating client connection, connectString=172.31.28.73:2181,172.31.38.251:2181,172.31.38.252:2181/storm sessionTimeout=20000 watcher=org.apache.storm.curator.ConnectionState@3f308697
2015-06-25T19:42:32.727+0000 o.a.s.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Opening socket connection to server 172.31.28.73/172.31.28.73:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2015-06-25T19:42:32.727+0000 o.a.s.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Socket connection established to 172.31.28.73/172.31.28.73:2181, initiating session
2015-06-25T19:42:32.733+0000 o.a.s.z.ClientCnxn [INFO] Session establishment complete on server 172.31.28.73/172.31.28.73:2181, sessionid = 0x14e2b0caa010061, negotiated timeout = 20000
2015-06-25T19:42:32.733+0000 o.a.s.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager [INFO] State change: CONNECTED
2015-06-25T19:42:32.774+0000 b.s.d.worker [INFO] Reading Assignments.
2015-06-25T19:42:32.838+0000 b.s.m.TransportFactory [INFO] Storm peer transport plugin:backtype.storm.messaging.netty.Context
2015-06-25T19:42:32.971+0000 b.s.d.worker [INFO] Launching receive-thread for 58e551ba-f944-4aec-9c8f-5621053021dd:6703
2015-06-25T19:42:32.983+0000 b.s.m.n.Server [INFO] Create Netty Server Netty-server-localhost-6703, buffer_size: 10485760, maxWorkers: 4
2015-06-25T19:42:33.011+0000 b.s.m.loader [INFO] Starting receive-thread: [stormId: tpch-q5-top-6-1435261345, port: 6703, thread-id: 0 ]
2015-06-25T19:42:33.041+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] creating Netty Client, connecting to ip-172-31-19-254.us-west-2.compute.internal:6703, bufferSize: 10485760
2015-06-25T19:42:33.041+0000 o.a.s.c.r.ExponentialBackoffRetry [WARN] maxRetries too large (100). Pinning to 29
2015-06-25T19:42:33.041+0000 b.s.u.StormBoundedExponentialBackoffRetry [INFO] The baseSleepTimeMs [100] the maxSleepTimeMs [1000] the maxRetries [100]
2015-06-25T19:42:33.042+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] connection attempt 1 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-19-254.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.19.254:6703 scheduled to run in 0 ms
2015-06-25T19:42:33.067+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection attempt 1 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-19-254.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.19.254:6703 failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Returned channel was actually not established
2015-06-25T19:42:33.068+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] connection attempt 2 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-19-254.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.19.254:6703 scheduled to run in 103 ms
2015-06-25T19:42:33.071+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] creating Netty Client, connecting to ip-172-31-13-184.us-west-2.compute.internal:6703, bufferSize: 10485760
2015-06-25T19:42:33.071+0000 o.a.s.c.r.ExponentialBackoffRetry [WARN] maxRetries too large (100). Pinning to 29
2015-06-25T19:42:33.071+0000 b.s.u.StormBoundedExponentialBackoffRetry [INFO] The baseSleepTimeMs [100] the maxSleepTimeMs [1000] the maxRetries [100]
2015-06-25T19:42:33.076+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] connection attempt 1 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-13-184.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.13.184:6703 scheduled to run in 0 ms
2015-06-25T19:42:33.080+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] creating Netty Client, connecting to ip-172-31-19-254.us-west-2.compute.internal:6702, bufferSize: 10485760
2015-06-25T19:42:33.080+0000 o.a.s.c.r.ExponentialBackoffRetry [WARN] maxRetries too large (100). Pinning to 29
2015-06-25T19:42:33.080+0000 b.s.u.StormBoundedExponentialBackoffRetry [INFO] The baseSleepTimeMs [100] the maxSleepTimeMs [1000] the maxRetries [100]
2015-06-25T19:42:33.080+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] connection attempt 1 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-19-254.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.19.254:6702 scheduled to run in 0 ms
2015-06-25T19:42:33.081+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] creating Netty Client, connecting to ip-172-31-13-184.us-west-2.compute.internal:6702, bufferSize: 10485760
2015-06-25T19:42:33.082+0000 o.a.s.c.r.ExponentialBackoffRetry [WARN] maxRetries too large (100). Pinning to 29
2015-06-25T19:42:33.082+0000 b.s.u.StormBoundedExponentialBackoffRetry [INFO] The baseSleepTimeMs [100] the maxSleepTimeMs [1000] the maxRetries [100]
2015-06-25T19:42:33.082+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] connection attempt 1 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-13-184.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.13.184:6702 scheduled to run in 0 ms
2015-06-25T19:42:33.084+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] creating Netty Client, connecting to ip-172-31-19-254.us-west-2.compute.internal:6701, bufferSize: 10485760
2015-06-25T19:42:33.084+0000 o.a.s.c.r.ExponentialBackoffRetry [WARN] maxRetries too large (100). Pinning to 29
2015-06-25T19:42:33.084+0000 b.s.u.StormBoundedExponentialBackoffRetry [INFO] The baseSleepTimeMs [100] the maxSleepTimeMs [1000] the maxRetries [100]
2015-06-25T19:42:33.084+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] connection attempt 1 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-19-254.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.19.254:6701 scheduled to run in 0 ms
2015-06-25T19:42:33.162+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection attempt 1 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-13-184.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.13.184:6703 failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Returned channel was actually not established
2015-06-25T19:42:33.162+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] creating Netty Client, connecting to ip-172-31-13-184.us-west-2.compute.internal:6701, bufferSize: 10485760
2015-06-25T19:42:33.162+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] connection attempt 2 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-13-184.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.13.184:6703 scheduled to run in 103 ms
2015-06-25T19:42:33.163+0000 o.a.s.c.r.ExponentialBackoffRetry [WARN] maxRetries too large (100). Pinning to 29
```

and

```
2015-06-25T19:42:33.176+0000 b.s.u.StormBoundedExponentialBackoffRetry [INFO] The baseSleepTimeMs [100] the maxSleepTimeMs [1000] the maxRetries [100]
2015-06-25T19:42:33.176+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] connection attempt 1 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-19-253.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.19.253:6700 scheduled to run in 0 ms
2015-06-25T19:42:33.178+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection attempt 1 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-13-184.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.13.184:6700 failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Returned channel was actually not established
2015-06-25T19:42:33.189+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection attempt 2 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-19-254.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.19.254:6703 failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Returned channel was actually not established
2015-06-25T19:42:33.190+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] connection attempt 2 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-13-184.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.13.184:6700 scheduled to run in 103 ms
2015-06-25T19:42:33.191+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] connection attempt 3 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-19-254.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.19.254:6703 scheduled to run in 105 ms
2015-06-25T19:42:33.195+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection attempt 1 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-19-253.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.19.253:6700 failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Returned channel was actually not established
2015-06-25T19:42:33.195+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] connection attempt 2 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-19-253.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.19.253:6700 scheduled to run in 102 ms
2015-06-25T19:42:33.196+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection attempt 1 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-19-252.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.19.252:6702 failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Returned channel was actually not established
2015-06-25T19:42:33.196+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] connection attempt 2 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-19-252.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.19.252:6702 scheduled to run in 102 ms
2015-06-25T19:42:33.197+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection attempt 1 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-19-252.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.19.252:6700 failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Returned channel was actually not established
2015-06-25T19:42:33.198+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] connection attempt 2 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-19-252.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.19.252:6700 scheduled to run in 103 ms
2015-06-25T19:42:33.198+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection attempt 1 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-19-252.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.19.252:6703 failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Returned channel was actually not established
2015-06-25T19:42:33.198+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection attempt 1 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-19-253.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.19.253:6702 failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Returned channel was actually not established
2015-06-25T19:42:33.205+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] connection attempt 2 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-19-252.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.19.252:6703 scheduled to run in 103 ms
2015-06-25T19:42:33.198+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] connection established to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-19-252.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.19.252:6701
2015-06-25T19:42:33.206+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] connection attempt 2 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-19-253.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.19.253:6702 scheduled to run in 102 ms
2015-06-25T19:42:33.205+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] connection established to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-19-253.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.19.253:6701
2015-06-25T19:42:33.268+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection attempt 2 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-13-184.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.13.184:6703 failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Returned channel was actually not established
2015-06-25T19:42:33.272+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] connection attempt 3 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-13-184.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.13.184:6703 scheduled to run in 105 ms
2015-06-25T19:42:33.273+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection attempt 2 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-19-254.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.19.254:6701 failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Returned channel was actually not established
2015-06-25T19:42:33.273+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] connection attempt 3 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-19-254.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.19.254:6701 scheduled to run in 105 ms
2015-06-25T19:42:33.274+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] connection attempt 2 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-19-254.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.19.254:6702 failed: java.lang.RuntimeException: Returned channel was actually not established
2015-06-25T19:42:33.274+0000 b.s.m.n.Client [INFO] connection attempt 3 to Netty-Client-ip-172-31-19-254.us-west-2.compute.internal/172.31.19.254:6702 scheduled to run in 106 ms
2015-06-25T19:42:33.275+0000 b.s
```

Why am I getting the above. Initially, I thought that the input rate of tuples in my topology is too high, and Netty's buffers are filled up too fast. However, I submitted a debug topology 
that sent one tuple every 1 second and I still got the above messages.

Am I doing something wrong in my configuration? Why do I have the previous Netty messages, which obviously show that something is going wrong? Please, any hint on my setup will be really helpful.